# Does creating a database/collection cost something in Cosmos DB?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

- Does it cost anything every time you drop/recreate a **database** in Cosmos DB (SQL API)?
- Does it cost anything every time you drop/recreate a **collection** within a database in Cosmos DB (SQL API)?

Comment: Take a look at my answer, there are definitely billing implications of creating and dropping collections depending on how frequently you're doing it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Database, Collections, Offers, Documents etc all inherit from the same single object which is a `Resource`. Resources are basically a CosmosDB object which is represented in JSON.

Creating a collection or creating a database is essentially creating a `Resource` which is a document whose size doesn't exceed the 1kb so you will be charged the minimum price for the `Create` or `Read` of that data.

Keep in mind however that CosmosDB also charges you hourly per collection based on it's provisioned RUs. For example, if you create a collection even for a second, you will be charged the hourly rate of this collection's existence based on the provisioned RUs.

Comment: This is very misleading information when it comes to actual billing cost as compared to the consumed RU for specific operations.

Comment: @JesseCarter Now it's not

Comment: Didn't you just say exactly what I said ;)

JK have an upvote

Comment: The last bit is the most important - perhaps it should be listed first.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-resources#hierarchical-resource-model), databases, users, permissions, collections ,documents and attachments are all resources. Just as what is mentioned in this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/request-units), the billing unit for Cosmos DB is RUs. If you operate any resources in cosmos db , you will consume RUs so that costs will be incurred.

I tested code related to creating and dropping database via java cosmos db sdk.You could see the consumption of RUs with your operations.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception, DocumentClientException {

        DocumentClient documentClient = new DocumentClient(END_POINT,
                MASTER_KEY, ConnectionPolicy.GetDefault(),
                ConsistencyLevel.Session);

        Database database = new Database();
        database.setId("hello");

        ResourceResponse<Database> response = documentClient.createDatabase(database, null);
        System.out.println(response.getRequestCharge());

        ResourceResponse<Database> response1 = documentClient.deleteDatabase("dbs/hello", null);

        System.out.println(response1.getRequestCharge());

    }
```

[image]

Another details about price in cosmos db,please see this [doc](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cosmos-db/).

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Didn't you just say exactly what I said?

Answer (score 1):

Creating a Collection will incur one hour of billing at whatever RU/s throughput you have provisioned. Same as with scaling. IE if you scale up from 1000RU/s to 2000RU/s and then back down immediately you'll still be charged for one hour usage at 2000RU/s.

The [Azure Pricing Calculator](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-ca/pricing/calculator/) will let you break down the cost of a collection in hourly granularity based on the provisioned throughput.

Answer (score 1):

Cosmos DB pricing completely depends on **reserve RU** per collection, You don't need to pay anything for creating Cosmos DB account and Database but when you will create a collection, minimum RU limit is 400 per collection, so if you use or not that collection you need to pay.